# DB2 to Postgres Function

Tags: postgresql, db2

I  need to change function of db2 to posgtgre

Comment: What exactly does that number represent? Days since when?

Comment: Here what is office doc has been said about days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a FROM clause in Postgre**s** to begin with.

The function seems to return the number of days since `0001-01-01` which can be express in Postgres as:

```
select current_date - date '0001-01-01';
```

Comment: This function giving exact output as db2 , i will try this 
Thanks